# Circular View Path Error, Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, view

I'm trying to do the tutorial -> http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

When I run it, it says Circular View Path[greeting], why?

In the tutorial, one thing i dont understand is what the following does and why it works:

```
return "greeting";
```

Code snippet:

```
package hello;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problems in your code. Please show your error.

Comment: This did the trick for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114681/when-spring-boot-application-running-by-intelij-idea-views-cant-be-resolved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have skipped a step while following the tutorial.

I'll explain why you get the behavior you are seeing and you can decide what to do afterwards.

You probably started your application the

```
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

in the tutorial `Application` class' `main` method. By default, because of `@EnableAutoConfiguration` (and other components on the classpath), a `DispatcherServlet` will be registered for you which provides a default `UrlBasedViewResolver` that doesn't set a `prefix` or `suffix` to the views it resolves.

In your `@Controller` handler method, when you do

```
return "greeting";
```

Spring will use the `UrlBasedViewResolver` to resolve a view name. In this case, the view name will simply be `greeting`. In normal cases, once that is done, it will use the `Servlet` API's `HttpServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher(String)` passing in that view name. That method returns a `RequestDispatcher` which points to the handler for that path.

In our case, before getting the `RequestDispatcher`, Spring will compare the view name (which resolves to a path) and the current request's path. It will find that they are both equal. In other words, a request to `/greeting` will be handled by returning a view to `/greeting` which will be handled by the same `@Controller` handler method, and this forever. Spring detects this and tells you that you have a circular view path, ie. you would loop infinitely.

Find out how `@EnableAutoConfiguration` works and change your configuration so that you can define your own `UrlBasedViewResolver` or `InternalResourceViewResolver` which sets prefix and suffix appropriately.

---

You can read more about *view name resolution* in the [official Spring MVC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).

Comment: Hey Sotirios, is there any difference if I start the application by running 'SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);' and by generating a .war and running java -jar app.war? I'm asking because I've got the same error, but it only happens when I run the application from the IDE, if I run it from the war file it works fine.

Comment: @GlauberNéspoli The only potential difference is your classpath. Check that you've set your runtime classpath correctly (ie. matching your `-jar` case) in the IDE.

Answer (score 8):

check your dependencies in .pom if it has

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Adding this dependency solved my circular view path error

Answer (score 2):

`public String greeting(){}` should be written to `public **@ResponseBody** String greeting(){}`,
thus spring mvc will not return a view and your problem will go.

Comment: This solved the problem for me.  Though my method had to have more parameters than `public @ResponseBody String greeting(){}`.  Not sure why this answer got down-voted.  Adding `@ResponseBody` to what I already had (and giving a return type string) solved my problem.

Comment: @CodeMed It was probably downvoted because it goes against the intended behavior of the tutorial and question. The return value `"greeting"` is intended as a view name for a Thymeleaf view. If they annotated the method with `@ResponseBody`, `"greeting"` is returned literally in the response body. That's not what they want.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you for clarifying. I think most people find these postings by googling error messages. I would imagine that mosr people who find this dont use Thymeleaf. Kinda funny that a lousy answer for the OP becomrs just what some of the future googlers need.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are hitting the `/greeting` controllew which returns a string `greeting`.
But the view resolver of Spring what actually trying to do is redirecting to a view named `greeting` which is not available here. So you just add `@ResponseBody` in your method and it would solve your problem.

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public @ResponseBody String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when following the [given](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) tutorial.
There has been an error in my maven dependencies and I could fix the problem by removing  **.m2**  folder and installing dependencies again.

Answer (score 0):

[When Spring Boot application running by Intelij Idea views can`t be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114681/when-spring-boot-application-running-by-intelij-idea-views-cant-be-resolved)

Adding

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

did the trick for me when nothing else worked.