# When Spring Boot application running by Intelij Idea views can`t be resolved

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-boot, maven-plugin

I have encountered a strange situation, the decision which I cant find.
I`m runnig simple demo application using Spring Boot 1.3.0 and Intelij Idea 14.1.3

The problem is that Spring MVC cant resolve the view:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Oddity is that when I run application by Maven Spring Boot-plugin

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run
```

everythig works fine.

Both views ("home.jsp" - returning from Controller and "start.jsp" - described in Configuration class) resolve correctly.

Full source code you can see [here](https://github.com/vdemus/spring-demo)

I`ve downloaded [another demo project](https://github.com/mariuszs/spring-boot-web-jsp-example) - the same situation.

So, I think that something wrong with my IDE configuration. 
But what is going wrong - I don`t know.

In File->Project Structure

I have added Spring and web module in "Modules" tab, the same I`ve made in "Facets" tab.

What is possible to do to make application run correctly using IDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem was in dependecies configuration in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have change `<scope>provided</scope>` to `<scope>compile</scope>` and it works well.

Comment: Was having the same problem for quite some time and this solved, thanks a lot!

Comment: Same problem, wasted hours - your solution. It works, @Workin_Man!

Comment: Thank you so much, I spend several hours looking for such a simple thing. I had scope to provided as well! Changed it to compile and it works right away.